# Use Timer in another Timer in C#

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I have a windows service project with this code:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)       
 {  
      InitializeScheduler(); 
      var timer = new Timer {Interval = 10 * 60 * 1000};
      timer.Elapsed += (ss, ee) => InitializeScheduler();
      timer.Start(); 
 }
 private void InitializeScheduler()
 {
      _taskScheduler = new TaskScheduler() { Enabled = true };
      // do something
 }
```

in TaskScheduler class:

```
private Timer _triggerTimer;
        public TaskScheduler()
        {            
            _triggerTimer = new Timer(1000);
            _triggerTimer.Elapsed += (TriggerTimerTick);
        }
```

When I instance "TaskScheduler" in  "InitializeScheduler()",  _triggerTimer is not dispose and add another timer. How can I dispose it and restart all things in  InitializeScheduler() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to dispose the timer before creating a new one.

```
private void InitializeScheduler()
{
if( _taskScheduler != null)
    _taskScheduler.Dispose();

     _taskScheduler = new TaskScheduler() { Enabled = true };
    // do something
 }
```

TaskScheduler class:

```
private Timer _triggerTimer;
public TaskScheduler()
{            
    _triggerTimer = new Timer(1000);
    _triggerTimer.Elapsed += (TriggerTimerTick);
}

public Dispose()
{
   if(_triggerTimer != null){
       _triggerTimer.Dispose()
       _triggerTimer = null;
}
```